# Intent that changes activity doesn't work

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I created a simple counter and want to add a button that proceeds to another activity, here's what I got:

```
//counter starts
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == btn1){
        counter++;
        scoreText.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
        scoreText.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
    }
    if (v == btn2){
        counter--;
        scoreText.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
        scoreText.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }

    if (v == btn3){
        counter = 0;
        scoreText.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
        scoreText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
    //There the counter ends
        next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SecondAcitivity.this, Aktivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }});
    }}
```

After the `//There the counter ends` tag I set an OnClickListener to a button "NEXT" that proceeds to another activity and created an Intent that brings to the activity  called "Aktivity".
When I press the button, however, nothing happnendz. halp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cut and Paste this code in your onCreate() Method

```
next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SecondAcitivity.this, Aktivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }});
```

You can't set click listener to an object inside onClick() Method

Comment: Ok, I tested the above scenario and I experienced that it is possible to add click listener to an object inside some click event. Posting the code in my answer.

Comment: @AnkitGarg   Its not working. You better check it before posting any such comment. It will only work user already pressed button 1. Otherwise it will not work. its not general solution.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
Button b1, b2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.f);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.s);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    b1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            b2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

@Brontok I tested this code and it works fine. So, onClick on an object can be implemented inside other onClick.

@MiroslavVitula I tested your scenario too. I was able to open the same activity by same method you used. Maybe some other problem.

Comment: Actually when we add the onClickListener in onCreate, we use "this" as the argument to pass context. Now, to add listener outside, we need the context.

Comment: Its not working. You better check it before posting any such comment. It will only work user already pressed button 1. Otherwise it will not work. its not general solution.

Comment: Oh I got it now. I thought Miroslav want to enable the 2nd button only when he click one of other. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

switch(v.getId())
{
case R.id.btn1: // btn1 clicked
        counter++;
        scoreText.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
        scoreText.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
break;
case R.id.btn2: // btn2 clicked
        counter--;
        scoreText.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
        scoreText.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
break;
case R.id.btn1: // btn3 clicked
        counter=0;
        scoreText.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
        scoreText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
break;
case R.id.next: // assuming button next id is next. btn next clicked
          Intent intent = new Intent(SecondAcitivity.this, Aktivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);
break;
}
}
```

Then in onCreate

```
next.setOnClickListener(this); // similarly fro other buttons
```

Ans make sure your Activity implements `OnClickListener`

Instead of `switch case` you can use `if else`.